# How to run the curl comand in loops

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

I am using the following curl command for testing something.it send auth requests to the URl using the username and password mentioned.But then now I have to run it in loop for 1000 times with Username and password as variable inputs?Any idea on how this can be done?
It could be in Curl or a perl or python which inturn uses this curl command

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%F IN (1,1,1) DO curl -k -d @curldata.xml -A "Apple-iPhone8C1/1302.143" -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.paos+xml" -H "X-MS-Client-User-Agent: Apple-iPad2C2/1302.143" --basic -u test:test123 https://x.x.x.x/dana-ws/xxxx.ws --trace-ascii -

ECHO.
```

Comment: Is this command working for you as a single output? Do you have to use the same username and password and the same URL for each curl command?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard this command is working for me...I need to try with the same URL but the username and password keeps changing..I have multiple tests where for some I have to send it with same user name and different passwords..Other one is diff username and same passwords and then with same user name and same passwords.The output will be like the URL receives multiple requests based on the count in (1,1,1) inputs

Comment: You can increase the counter `(1,1,1000)` I will see if I have a minute just now to post an answer for you.

Comment: Both Perl and Python are general purpose programming languages, it can be done also in .NET, Java, C++ and dozens of other languages. So I'm removing the tags.